# Unable to find all boundary points in absolute extrema question

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

> Consider the function $f(x,y) = x^3 - 6xy + y^2 + 15x$.
>
> Find the absolute extrema of $f$ over the triangular region in the $xy$-plane with vertices (0,0), (0,4), and (2,4).

I am using this graph to see that I am getting all of the points needed: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tnyu81h2j5

I was able to find the interior point just fine, but I'm having trouble finding all the boundary points.

**For x = 0, I got (0,0):**

$f(x,y) = f(0,y) = y^2$

$f' = 2y = 0 \implies y = 0$

**For y = 4, I got $(\sqrt{3}, 4)$:**

$f(x, y) = f(x, 4) = x^3 -24x + 16 + 15x = x^3 - 9x +16$

$f' = 3x^2 - 9 = 0$

$x = +/- \sqrt{3} \implies -\sqrt{3}$ is not in region

**But I am having trouble with y = 2x:**

$f(x, y) = f(x, 2x) = x^3 - 12x^2 + 4x^2 + 15 = x^3 - 8x^2 + 15x$

$f' = 3x^2 - 16x + 15$

$x = \frac{16 \pm \sqrt{76}}{6}$

These x-values are not lining up with the remaining two critical points on the boundary. What am I doing wrong? How do I find these other points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the line $y=2x$. You are doing the right thing when looking at what happens for the trinomial $x^3-8 x^2 +15x$.

You have to study it on the interval $x \in [0,2]$. The only root of the derivative in that interval is $x_1=\frac{16 + \sqrt{76}}{6}$ (the other one is outside the interval). $f(x,2x)$ is having a maximum at $x_1$. You can then compare the value of this maximum vs. the other local maximum that you found.

Comment: Thank you. So, what you're saying is that the only boundary points I should get are (0,0), $(\sqrt{3}, 4)$, and $(\frac{16 + \sqrt{76}}{6}, \frac{16 + \sqrt{76}}{3}$), as well as the corner points?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: On a second glance... ($\frac{16 + \sqrt{76}}{6}$, $\frac{16 + \sqrt{76}}{3}$) would be outside the interval too, right? Since $\frac{16 + \sqrt{76}}{3}$ is greater than 4. So, would I not count this point either?

Comment: Exact too!!!!!!!!